# My DT overlay doesn't work

Tags: gpio, uart

I'm trying to activate the miniUART with RTS and CTS signals (on an RPi Compute Module).

For this purpose I've created an overlay:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/*
   Enable /dev/ttyS0 with RTS and CTS signals
   TX is available on GPIO 32
   RX is available on GPIO 33
   CTS is available on GPIO 30
   RTS is available on GPIO 31
*/

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&uart1>;
        __overlay__ {
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&uart1_gpio32 &uart1_ctsrts_gpio30>;
        };
    };
};
```

I have compiled it to `uart1-full.dtbo` and added this to `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtoverlay=uart1-full
```

However, there is no `/dev/ttyS0` presented after reboot.

What can be the problem? How can I check if my dtbo was loaded correctly?

Note: if I use the bundled `uart1` overlay, it creates `/dev/ttyS0` for me and it's usable (without CTS and RTS of course).

My kernel is quite new:

```
Linux DietPi 5.10.52+ #1441 Tue Aug 3 18:08:18 BST 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux
```